# how to connect react with redux?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, store

so I am trying to learn about react-redux using react-native and I want to make a page where I can input a number and press login. when I press login, the page will alert me the number I input and saved into the store I created with redux.

can anyone please tell me what i'm doing wrong and what should I add or do to make it work?

below is my testing page

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import actions from '../Redux/Action';

class tes extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <TextInput placeholder="phone number"
                    keyboardType="number-pad"/>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onLogin}>
                    <Text>login</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        number: state.phoneNumber
    }
}

mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onLogin: (number) => {
            dispatch(actions.setLoginNumber(number))
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(tes);
```

this is my store class

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';

import reducer from './Reducer';

export default createStore(reducer)
```

here is my reducer class

```
 const reducer = (state = {
    phoneNumber: '',
},action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "LOGIN":
            state = {
                phoneNumber: action.payload
            }
            break;
    }
    return state;
}

export default reducer;


{/* and this one my action class */}

    export default function setLoginNumber(number) {
        return{
            type: "LOGIN",
            payload: number
        };
    }
```

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I think your not passing parameter number to onLogin function and you will need local state variable to hold the value. The code should be like this

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import actions from '../Redux/Action';

class tes extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
           number: 0,
        };
    }
 render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <TextInput placeholder="phone number"
                    onChangeText={inputNumber => {
                      this.setState({ number: inputNumber })
                    }}
                    keyboardType="number-pad"/>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.props.onLogin(this.state.number) }}>
                    <Text>login</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        number: state.phoneNumber
    }
}

mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onLogin: (number) => {
            dispatch(actions.setLoginNumber(number))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer for your second question - 
You haven't passed created store to provider component of react-redux like below example

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import store from './store';

export default class Root extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
render() {
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <App />
        </Provider>
      );

  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it throws me another error saying typeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'store.getState()')